# Why does kafka-consumer-groups produce no output for listed consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

When I run the command:

```
kafka-consumer-groups -bootstrap-server localhost:9092 -list
```

It produces a list of consumer groups.  Here's some lengthy output:

```
$ kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.
simulate_birdfeeder.e67c034c-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
xfer_server.e65d3732-a96d-11e9-992f-983b8f0e47c8
xfer_server.e654e596-a96d-11e9-992f-983b8f0e47c8
scheduler_node.e6ba65ce-a96d-11e9-b125-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_birdfeeder.e695c336-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_birdfeeder.e681a4c8-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
scheduler_node.e6b936f4-a96d-11e9-b125-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_birdfeeder.e6956c2e-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
scheduler_node.e6de0222-a96d-11e9-b125-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_birdfeeder.e68ec02c-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
scheduler_node.e6b48f82-a96d-11e9-b125-983b8f0e47c8
scheduler_node.e6b436cc-a96d-11e9-b125-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_birdfeeder.e68fed3a-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_birdfeeder.e658faf0-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_birdfeeder.e64f28ea-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_birdfeeder.e691a710-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_birdfeeder.e6889f30-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
74b6a2e3-efe6-4a62-ad6b-a4782038db43
simulate_birdfeeder.e67ec7bc-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_birdfeeder.e67b9178-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_birdfeeder.e65b4b2a-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
scheduler_node.e6dcad1e-a96d-11e9-b125-983b8f0e47c8
water_connector
simulate_birdfeeder.e6924904-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
reporter
xfer_server.e652ee8a-a96d-11e9-992f-983b8f0e47c8
scheduler_node.e68d3446-a96d-11e9-b125-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_flexcharger.e560bef8-a96d-11e9-a249-983b8f0e47c8
511bcf37-7e6b-4a33-9a57-9ad498f9a089
simulator.e5d05a10-a96d-11e9-9375-983b8f0e47c8
trajectory.queue
simulate_birdfeeder.e662497a-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
scheduler
simulate_birdfeeder.e6874ca2-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
85f138e2-bb87-4885-98b8-a6536595cf7c
scheduler_node.e69bcd9e-a96d-11e9-b125-983b8f0e47c8
scheduler_node.e69b0c42-a96d-11e9-b125-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_birdfeeder.e6612c7a-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
scheduler_node.e691649e-a96d-11e9-b125-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_birdfeeder.e665d02c-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_birdfeeder.e6554ab8-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
xfer_server.e65b81ee-a96d-11e9-992f-983b8f0e47c8
server.e6159012-a96d-11e9-bbdf-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_birdfeeder.e666c9b4-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_birdfeeder.e67dffb2-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
KMOffsetCache-my-computer
simulate_birdfeeder.e697c230-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_birdfeeder.e683e0bc-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_birdfeeder.e65fbd40-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_birdfeeder.e69706c4-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
scheduler_node.e69cc438-a96d-11e9-b125-983b8f0e47c8
xfer_server.e64a93de-a96d-11e9-992f-983b8f0e47c8
scheduler_node.e6a55e72-a96d-11e9-b125-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_birdfeeder.e685be50-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
product_monitor
simulate_birdfeeder.e688f89a-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_birdfeeder.e66b29fa-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_birdfeeder.e6811242-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
scheduler_node.e6a62be0-a96d-11e9-b125-983b8f0e47c8
scheduler_node.e6b9fa58-a96d-11e9-b125-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_birdfeeder.e68a2986-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_birdfeeder.e690480c-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
server.e60fec02-a96d-11e9-bbdf-983b8f0e47c8
scheduler_node.e6a45856-a96d-11e9-b125-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_birdfeeder.e68385ae-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
server
simulate_birdfeeder.e668c246-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
simulate_birdfeeder.e65f11a6-a96d-11e9-861a-983b8f0e47c8
xfer_server.e64f2bb0-a96d-11e9-992f-983b8f0e47c8
scheduler_node.e6b8e834-a96d-11e9-b125-983b8f0e47c8
scheduler_node.e6ddb13c-a96d-11e9-b125-983b8f0e47c8
```

Of which I can describe them:

```
$ kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group server
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.

TOPIC                PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                  HOST            CLIENT-ID
reservationist.queue 0          456             456             0               rdkafka-fa9be154-c7ac-471f-a9d1-5bfd3f42da8c /127.0.0.1      rdkafka
```

However, for some consumer groups, if I describe them, there is no output at all.  I'll get something like the following:

```
$ kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group scheduler_node.e6ddb13c-a96d-11e9-b125-983b8f0e47c8
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.
```

Aside from the warning, there is no output, but the consumer does exist, because it is listed in the former list command.  Now, if I use the zookeeper option, the command complains about the group not existing.

Often the consumers that look like `widget` has a description of offsets, and the ones that look like `widget.some-long-random-string` have no output. And consumers that look like `some-long-random-string` also produce a description with offsets.

(I'm not 100% certain, but I'm pretty sure the missing consumer groups are subscribed to, otherwise my application would be bombing, which isn't the case.)

I am using confluent kafka locally.  My code and confluent are all running in my dev box:

```
$ confluent version kafka
This CLI is intended for development only, not for production
https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html

1.1.1-cp1
```

Can any give me some insight as to what is going on?  Thanks.

Comment: When you say "there is no output at all" what exactly do you mean? Can you please share an example output?

Comment: OK, I will edit my post.

Comment: Okay, it will take some time, I will have to replace some of the identifiers, I'm sure my company will be wary of me giving away their secrets.  Are you a kafka developer?

Comment: I believe it will not show the the information if consumers of that group are not active @Bitdiot

Comment: By active, do you mean offsets committed?

Answer (score 0):

```
kafka-consumer-groups \
  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
  --describe \
  --group your_consumer_group_name
```

will return no output if the consumers in the consumer group have not committed any offsets.

---

If the output of

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh \
  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
  --describe \
  --group server
```

and

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh \
  --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \
  --new-consumer
  --describe \
  --group server
```

matches and the consumer group appears in both consumer groups list output, my guess is that your consumers inside the consumer group `server` have not committed any offsets and this is why no information appears using the *describe* command.

---

Make sure that your consumers inside `server` group commit their offsets succesfully (either manually or automatically).